# How to query by string

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-urls

In Product model and i want to query by food title. and return me `NoReverseMatch` error

html url:

```
<a href="{% url 'product' food_name=catalog.food_name|urlencode %}">some text</a>
```

views.py:

```
def product(request, food_name):
    product = Catalog.objects.get(food_name=food_name)
    return render(request, 'food/product.html', {'product':product})
```

url.py

```
url(r'^product/(?P<food_name>\w+)/', food_views.product, name='product'),
```

Trace

```
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'product' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{u'food_name': u'%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1%DA%A9'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: [u'product/(?P<food_name>\\w+)/']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because `\w+` doesn't match URL-encoded string. Try to change it *temporarily* to `.*` (just to check if there are not any other issues). If it will work — change `\w+` to better template matching URL-encoded strings.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `urlencode`, you don't need it

```
<a href="{% url 'product' food_name=catalog.food_name %}">some text</a>
```

`urlencode` is used when you need to encode a string in a way that will allow it to be used inside a url (such as when you're adding get parameters). Above, you are just passing a string parameter to a function that is constructing a url.

---

You seem to be trying to encode arabic characters into your url which are not matched by `\w` so you need to update your url to support these

```
^product/(?P<food_name>[\w\u0600-\u06FF]+)/
```

Will handle most of these (See [this regexr example](http://regexr.com/3f2bo)), but I'm not familiar with arabic enough to know what the unicode for `ک` is

Comment: which is a different matter. this answers your question +1

Comment: @ehsan - I didn't realise you were trying to include arabic in your url, I've updated my answer.

Comment: when I run the changes that you say, return ascii' codec error

Comment: @ehsan - Again, that is a different issue - one that you are going to come across a lot whilst using python 2.7